# Is there a way to install other OSes with Linux from from an ISO, without a CD drive?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, iso-image

Suppose I don't have any USB/CD/DVD etc.

I only have an ISO of any other operating system (in my current case, Win10, but I think it doesn't matter) on my desktop.

Is there any way to do fresh installation of that, beside my Linux Mint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only way I can think of is a very roundabout way.

1. Install the ISO in a Virtual Machine. Ensure the machine's architecture matches your own.
2. Create an image of the Machine's drive.
3. Create a partition that holds enough space to extract the Windows partition.
4. Extract the Windows image from the virtual machine on the newly created partition.
5. Create the entry for Windows partition in the grub config.

Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

Beside @NoniKhanna 's excellent answer, there is another way.

Some of the Linux bootloaders (at least grub1 ([ref](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46574313#46574313))) *can boot an ISO image from a Linux filesystem*.

Thus, you can boot the Win10 iso image directly with Grub1, and install it with that.

This has the positive side-effect that the Win10 will be installed on the physical machine directly, thus it won't experience a hardware change as you boot it first directly.

You might also need to re-partition your Linux hard drive. It could be done by booting a Live system (for example, an Ubuntu Live) with the same way, before your Win10 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

- It is unlikely that Microsoft have written an installer that runs on Linux, so you will have to run the install on the bare machine.
- Linux usually uses an `ext` file-system e.g. (ext4), Mircosoft OSs and installers can't read this file-system.

May be you can make a new partition of FAT file-system (or other filesystem that support Microsoft's installel), and copy the file there. If you hardware's boot loader and the installer, supports it then you can load the installer from there. But this is now becoming a Mircosoft Windows question, so you should ask a new question on the appropriate site.

Comment: Well, you could use ext2fsd for Windows, or really even install Linux to an NTFS partition -- getting the file modes right would be troublesome but not impossible.